# Read new-lines in textarea BEFORE submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an textarea with attribute wrap="hard", meaning I should be able to get the line break (new lines) after submit to server - this works. But what I wanna do is get the new lines that are created *before* submission.

Why? Because I wanna count the rows that are currently visible. And now I'm NOT talking about carriage return rows. I'm talking about rows that are created by limiting the width (or setting the cols attribute) of the textarea.

*I have this textbox:*

```
<textarea id="myarea" name="myarea" cols="35" rows="10" wrap="hard">
  Some example text here. Hello my name is something I should be able to blabla.
</textarea>
```

*Output in browser:*
Some example text here. Hello my name is 
something I should be able to blabla.

rows = 2

*I've tried:*
$('#myarea').html().split("\n").length
$('#myarea').val().split("< br>").length
$('#myarea').val().split("\r").length
And a few more combinations...

But none works. Is what I'm asking even possible without writing a script that counts each character and then creates a newline? I was hoping this would happend "automatically"...

If this is not possible, why can the server interpret (find) the new lines, while I can not?

Thanks!

Comment: _“why can the server interpret (find) the new lines, while I can not?”_ – http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-textarea-wrap

Comment: Thank you for that link. In my understanding (very little of that) shouldn't I be able to look for the "LF" (U+000A) character? And if that's the case, what "character" am I looking for then? :)

Comment: Line breaks originating from wrap=hard are not included in the `value` attribute you can read with JS – they are part of the “submit value”, but AFAIK it’s up to the browser when he “calculates” that - might be just in the moment the form gets submitted.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Couldn't quite understand that from the link! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is no build in tools to get this value. But we can calculate it.
Assume that the line-height in textarea is a known value (you can explicitly define it in css). So the code to calculate the number of rows would like this:

```
    var area = $('#myarea').get(0);

    //save the initial height of textarea
    var initialHeight = area.style.height;

    //set the height to 0 so scrollHeight will always return dynamic height
    area.style.height = '0px';

    //here we assume that the line-height equals to 15
    var numberOfRows = Math.floor(area.scrollHeight / 15);

    //restore textarea height
    area.style.height = initialHeight;

    console.log(numberOfRows);
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/J5UpF/

**UPDATE**

Just figured out the bug in Chrome with my code. I didn't take into account the scrollbar that appears on the right side of textarea. That leads to the wrong number of lines calculated sometimes. However it works like a charm in Firefox. To fix this issue we have to calculate the difference of scrollbars width and adjust the width of textarea accordingly:

```
var area = $('#myarea').get(0);
var $area = $('#myarea');

//save the initial height of textarea
var initialHeight = area.style.height;

var scrollbarWidthInitial = area.offsetWidth - area.clientWidth;

//set the height to 0 so scrollHeight will always return dynamic height
area.style.height = '0px';

var scrollbarWidth = area.offsetWidth - area.clientWidth;
var scrollbarWidthDiff = scrollbarWidth - scrollbarWidthInitial;
$area.width($area.width() + scrollbarWidthDiff);

//here we assume that the line-height equals to 15
var numberOfRows = Math.floor(area.scrollHeight / 15);

//restore textarea height
area.style.height = initialHeight;
$area.width($area.width() - scrollbarWidthDiff);

console.log(numberOfRows);
```

updated example http://jsfiddle.net/J5UpF/3/

**UPDATE 2**

A new awesome bug in Chrome is discovered! When using `placeholder` attribute Chrome calculates the number of rows for placeholder text. The workaround is simple: just backup the placeholder attribute when you entered some data into textarea and restore it when data is cleared.

Updated example http://jsfiddle.net/J5UpF/4/

Comment: Would you mind posting a working jsfiddle example with this? Tried the solution (quickly) but couldn't get it to work? :)

Comment: Updated the answer with jsFiddle

Comment: Works splendid! Thank you! - Marked as answer

Comment: Ahh thank you for the update! I used chrome when testing but didn't experience the bug! :)

Comment: It seems your code also counts placeholder text-rows (even when it's not visible). So the counter doesn't increase until you write _more_ then the placeholder text! It's still no problem for me but would be awesome if there was a way around this! Any ideas? :)

Answer (score -1):

You could bind jquery on the submit button onClick, then using

```
$('#myarea').val().split("\n").length
```